# How can I tell if (in VBA) if a document is opened from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, vba, ms-office

Is there a way to determine whether the current document (whether that be a Word document, Excel workbook or PowerPoint presentation) was opened from a SharePoint server?

It's the sort of thing that you'd think would have a property on ActiveDocument / ActiveWorkbook / ActivePresentation, but if there is such a property, I can't find it.

I could look at the FullName property, and see whether it begins http:// which I guess would be a reasonable hueristic, but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way.

If it makes a difference, let's assume Office 2007 or later (and SharePoint 2007 or later).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem some time ago and have not found clean way of determining this. The dirty way I used is analysing the origin path of the document and determining source based on it. It still has one or two pitfalls but should handle non-malevolent situations/users.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
'if default drafts location is not set in registry then exit
If IsNull(GetDefaultDrafts()) Then Exit Sub

'if document path includes 'http://' then it comes from SharePoint
If InStr(ActiveDocument.Path, "http://") = 1 Then
    'MsgBox ("Opened From SP")
    Exit Sub
    Else
    'if it does not
        If IsNull(GetCustomDrafts()) Then
            'if there is no custom location for drafts in registry
            'check if file path contains default location for drafts
            'if it does then it most likely comes from SharePoint
            If InStr(ActiveDocument.Path, GetDefaultDrafts()) = 1 Then
                'MsgBox ("Opened From SP")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox WarningMessage(), vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            'there is custom location for drafts
            If InStr(ActiveDocument.Path, GetCustomDrafts()) = 1 Then
                'MsgBox ("Opened From SP")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox WarningMessage(), vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetDefaultDrafts()
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
strValueName = "Personal"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
If IsNull(strValue) Then
    GetDefaultDrafts = Null
Else
    GetDefaultDrafts = strValue + "\SharePoint Drafts"
End If

End Function
```

---

```
Function GetCustomDrafts()
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Options"
strValueName = "Location"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
If IsNull(strValue) Then
    GetCustomDrafts = Null
Else
    GetCustomDrafts = strValue
End If

End Function
```

---

```
Function WarningMessage()
WarningMessage = "It seems that this document has not been opened from SharePoint library but from local copy instead. Local copies must not be used to preserve system functionality."
End Function
```

Comment: So, I guess this is dealing with situations where FullName (or Path) does not start "http://" (or "https://"), but it might still be from SharePoint if it's stored in the draft folder location. I hadn't considered that. Still seems incredible that there's no better way, though. I'd hoped that since there are *some* SP-related properties in VBA (CanCheckIn, SharedWorkspace), there would be one for this.

Comment: Indeed. It all depends if local drafts are used or not (and unfortunately it can be decided by user). If you happen to find that magic property let me know, it would solve many of my problems :)